# Magento2 REST API token validity

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, token, headless

As magento2, provides rest service to generate token for customer

```
rest/V1/integration/customer/token
```

Token expiration is provided from here

[image]

We are planning to use headless magento approach, with frontend web as a seperate app. If i use this token for validating session, how to keep different timeout for mobile and web?